# Specify trait for belongs_to assocation in Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I'm using Factory Girl, and I want to specify a belongs_to association that uses a trait. This code (without traits) works:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :challenge_participation do
    user
    challenge
    program
  end
end
```

But how would I add the `with_days` trait to my program? (The `with_days` trait sets up some has_many associations).

I imagine it'd be something like this, but I can't find the right syntax:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :challenge_participation do
    user
    challenge
    program :with_days # THIS DOESN'T WORK
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I'm an idiot. Figured it out, the `program` method accepts a block. So, you do it like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :challenge_participation do
    user
    challenge
    program { FactoryGirl.create(:program, :with_days) }
  end
end
```